# Where can I find the Avatar The Last Airbender: The Promise & The Search comics?

Tags: avatar

Where can I read *The Promise* trilogy and *The Search* trilogy? I've been looking everywhere since last year.

Comment: I don't think you can read it legally online, which means it's off-topic here.

Comment: You can purchase the the hardcover versions [here](http://www.amazon.com/Avatar-The-Last-Airbender-Promise/dp/1616550740) and [here](http://www.amazon.com/Avatar-The-Last-Airbender-Search/dp/1616552263/ref=pd_sim_b_1), respectively.

Comment: @kuwaly Isn't this question worthy of an actual answer? Some series are legal to read online and the OP didn't state whether legal or not.

Answer (score 2):

"You can purchase the the hardcover versions [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1616550740) and [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1616552263), respectively" - Krazer

After you purchase the comics and they have been delivered to you, you can then read the comics.